# .NET SQL Connection Leaking

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I made a class for DB connection like this:

```
public class DbHelper : IDisposable
{
private bool disposed;
public DbHelper()
{
    disposed = false;
}

public static SqlConnection ConnectionSender()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbname"].ConnectionString);
    return conn;
}

public System.Int32 ExecuteNonQuerySender(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    System.Int32 result;
    using (var conn = ConnectionSender())
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return result;
}

~DbHelper()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
        }
    }
    disposed = true;
}
}
```

I call this class `using` method:

```
var cmdParent = new SqlCommand { CommandText = sqlQuery };
using (var helper = new DbHelper())
{
            dt = helper.ExecuteNonQuerySender(cmdParent);
}
```

This works fine but my server is overloaded and I suspect about DB leaking. DB connection objects should be closed and disposed in this code. Did I do something wrong? (programmatically) 
I know there are also professional ways to solve DB connection but i want to try this code.

Comment: You should only use class destructors when de-allocating unmanaged resources.  Why are you using one here?  And are you *sure* it's the connection that is leaking?

Comment: Why is DbHelper IDisposable if you don't do anything in the Dispose method?

Comment: You sure its not something on the server such as numerous rows require indexing, massive amounts of concurrent request, bad configuration? Everything the code posted looks fine. Dispose is pointless since you don't hold reference to anything.

Comment: Where is DataTableSender in your DbHelper class?

Comment: Also, `ConnectionSender` is public so some code could be calling this method and not disposing the connection properly.

Comment: I used IDisposable beacuse i don't need that connection object after the query ends. I want to use `Using` and this method requires IDisposable. I know Dispose method is useless. Sorry DataTableSender is the wrong method. I changed.

Comment: The `using` will dispose of the connection object. Implementing IDisposable yourself isn't serving any purpose.

Comment: ConnectionSender is public but I am sure that it is just used internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it looks like you didn't give us the whole DbHelper class.  You don't show the `DataTableSender` method, but you use it in your example.

Secondly, assuming that there isn't anything unexpected in the rest of DBHelper, nothing in this class needs any of the dispose logic.  You can remove the `IDisposable` implementation entirely, along with the finalizer, the Dispose method, and the `disposed` variable, and it will make no difference (other than allowing you to remove the using clauses when using the class).  I'd recommend doing that and making the class a static class (requires making the ExecuteNonQuerySender method static also).

Finally, there is nothing here which is leaking connections, however callers could be 'leaking' connections if they call `ConnectionSender` and never close/dispose the connection that they get back.

Comment: I am curious about that using static class for DB connection is a unrelianble way or not. I am using the class for a website.

Comment: You're making a helper class, not a class for the connecton itself.  As long as you don't hold things in static variables, the static class wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually i create connections at the class according to SqlCommand. I the class uses twice at the same time which command will be used?

Comment: I think what you are asking is "if I use a static class, and two threads call the ExecuteNonQuery method at the same time, will they interfere with each other?".  If that's your question, the answer is no, they will not.  Each one will have it's own set of method arguments and variables on it's own call stack, and each one will create (and use) it's own connection object.

Answer (score 3):

> David M. Kean - MS Dev on Base Class Library Team: "**The exception to this is SqlConnection**, et al, Close does not mean the same as
> Dispose. Close closes the connection, but allows you  reuse the same
> connection instance later by calling Open. **Dispose  closes the
> connection, but does not allow you to reuse the same  connection
> instance.**"
>
> Stephen Cleary: "looking at SqlConnection in Reflector, Close and Dispose are not the
> same"
>
> Stephen Cleary: "I'm a smart guy (IMO), but David works for Microsoft. Source access trumps all other knowledge. ;)"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/b3587ccc-74e0-4575-9b60-7c529d2607ac

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't use "using" on your SQLConnection, the dispose will cause your connection to get removed from the connection pool and can hurt performance

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/b3587ccc-74e0-4575-9b60-7c529d2607ac

Comment: That's not what the article says.  It simply says that calling Close allows you to reopen the connection, whereas Dispose does not.  It doesn't mention the Pool at all.  In fact, further down you will find "P.S. Disposing DB connections by default will return them to the pool so they can be reused. This is an unusual implementation of Dispose, since it does not actually release the resources."

Comment: It doesn't remove the connection from the pool.

Comment: Learn to read guys, "Dispose closes the connection, but does not allow you to reuse the same connection instance." That's from the MS dev who writes the code for BCL. Someone else also responds to validate that statement via reflector.

Comment: Disposing a connection does not remove it from the pool.  I suggest you follow your own suggestion and read Chris' comment.  **Disposing DB connections by default will return them to the pool so they can be reused.**

Comment: @Inuyasha: If you read the ENTIRE post, you sill see that same person not only corrects himself, but the MS Dev corrects him and says he's wrong. Again, I state that I am not posting miss-information.